# Can I purchase the Windows 8 upgrade and install it on another PC?

Tags: windows-8

I want to upgrade to Windows 8. My one friend bought a new PC some days ago. He is not interested in windows 8 upgrade. Can I use his system details to upgrade to Windows 8 in 14.99$ on my PC which was bought two years ago.

Comment: Are you talking about the windows upgrade offer?

Comment: yea i m asking about windows upgrade offer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes you can!** (Providing you have **Windows 7**, excluding Windows 7 Starter Edition).

---

According to the [faq](http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-GB/Home/Faq) for the [Windows Upgrade Offer](http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-US):

> **Do I have to install the Windows 8 upgrade on the eligible PC, or can
>   I install it on another PC?**
>   The upgrade offer is tied to a Windows 7
>   PC purchased between 2 June 2012 and 31 January 2013, but you can
>   choose to redeem the offer and install the upgrade on any compatible
>   Windows-based PC with a qualifying base operating system.

---

> **Are all PCs purchased with Windows 7 between 2 June 2012 and 31 January 2013 eligible for the Upgrade Offer?**
>   Eligible PCs are new PCs purchased during the promotion period with a valid Windows 7 OEM Certificate of Authenticity, product key for and preinstalled with:
>
> Windows 7 Home Basic;
>   Windows 7 Home Premium;
>   Windows 7 Professional; or
>   Windows 7 Ultimate
>   **Note: Windows 7 Starter Edition is not eligible for this offer.**

Comment: Personally I wasn't expecting this to be the answer (but am happy it is!)

Answer (score 2):

While you can use the upgrade on another PC, also see [What happens to the Windows 7 key when upgrading to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/486959/what-happens-to-the-windows-7-key-when-upgrading-to-windows-8).

After you upgrade, the license for Windows 7 is no longer valid, and you no longer have a license to use Windows 7 on the original PC.

Does your friend have a Windows 7 license he can use instead? (Perhaps from a PC which will use the upgrade, if it is not OEM).