# Will Windows 8 be OEM when I upgrade a XP OEM pc?

Tags: windows-8, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I upgrade an OEM version of Windows XP to Windows 8, then transfer it to another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/493359/can-i-upgrade-an-oem-version-of-windows-xp-to-windows-8-then-transfer-it-to-ano)

Will Windows 8 be OEM when I upgrade a XP OEM PC?

Comment: To clarify for others: the biggest differences between OEM and Retail are the hardware lock and support. OEM licences are locked to the hardware, while retail may be transferred. Also, Microsoft provides support for retail (now 'personal use') licensees only, while OEMs are expected to provide their own support.

Comment: @HackToHell - The lack of research done on your part, multiple duplicate questions, dozens of technical articles answering this very question.

Comment: @KronoS The irony is that that is the very question that spawned this one: http://superuser.com/questions/493359/can-i-upgrade-an-oem-version-of-windows-xp-to-windows-8-then-transfer-it-to-ano#comment587845_493364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will Windows 8 be OEM when I upgrade a XP OEM PC?

No, the Windows 8 (Pro) Upgrade license explains, that the upgrade can be moved to different systems provided the previous system has Windows rolled back to the previous operating system.