# If I upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8, can I reuse my Windows 7 "full" license key on another partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, license, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to the Windows 7 key when upgrading to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/486959/what-happens-to-the-windows-7-key-when-upgrading-to-windows-8)

I would like to upgrade my Windows 7 PC to Windows 8. I currently have an academic license key for Windows 7, which is basically a full license key, not an upgrade. After the upgrade, I would still like to have a Windows 7 partition that I would create after the Windows 8 install.

Since the Windows 8 key is an upgrade key and Windows 7 key is a full key, does it kind of "deactivate" the Windows 7 key since I upgraded the OS? Or the Windows 7 key is still usable on my machine and it would be possible to install it along with Windows 8?

Comment: The Windows 7 product key is still valid, the license just isn't, which is a small but technical difference.  In other words ( you are not suppose to ) but there is no `technical` reason it cannot be done.  Since its the same system you might even be in the clear depending on some factors.

Comment: Related: [What happens to the Windows 7 key when upgrading to Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/q/486959/108226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Microsoft specifically mentions this in all its upgrade license terms. The previous version is replaced by the new upgraded vesion. You can't have it both ways - upgrade and keep old.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can- It is your license and you can use once per household as in the terms and conditions. So you can even move it over to another PC. Your upgrade does not allow you to upgrade the second one though!

EDIT

Ohh well I thought you could since I paid for both.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: Win 7 license does not say anything about upgrade limitations - only 1 pc per household(or user) - Upgrade says you can only upgrade 1 win7 PC - So technically the license are mutually exclusive because of that. Because Windows 8 is not Windows 7 any more.. So the Win 7 license is irrelevant.If you call up activation and it asks how many PC's is it on.. Ummm.. 1! OK- Activated. You paid for both so you are entitled to use them like that. If you pirated one then you will have issues with activation!

Comment: @ppumkin - Actually you are mistaken.  If you upgrade a Windows 7 license, the license is revoked, this means it cannot be used on another system.  The author's question of course is slightly different, the system will be the same, but technically the license is revoked ( at least up until ) the Windows 8 license is removed from said system and used to upgrade a differnet system.

Comment: Well I guess I should have read the terms and conditions that came with my digital download... And yes I knew that. Just making a point and giving you a chance to downvote the incorrect correct answer