# Downgrading from Windows 8 to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup Windows 7 and revert upgrade to Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/493643/how-to-backup-windows-7-and-revert-upgrade-to-windows-8)

I want to update my windows 7 to windows 8 but before I do so I would like to know if I can revert back to my previous version of windows (ie windows 7) in case of some compatibility issues or otherwise.

Also I have a genuine copy of windows 7 so will I have to purchase the licence key again and will this upgrade or downgrade be similar to a ubuntu upgrade? ( ie safe and smooth)

Comment: See [How to backup Windows 7 and revert upgrade to Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/493643/how-to-backup-windows-7-and-revert-upgrade-to-windows-8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, an upgrade is not reversible. But you can just make a backup and restore that, which should be the easiest option.