# Installing windows 8 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I downgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/474434/can-i-downgrade-from-windows-8-to-windows-7)

I had windows 7 installed on my Laptop,I installed windows 8 on it, without formatting the System Drive,Therefore now I can see two folders windows.old and Windows,The windows folder contain my new Windows 8, IS there any way that I can go back to Window 7? without formatting, This question is not programming related but I hope I can find some good answers here, If someone think that it is not fruitful, please comment on it, and I will delete that instead of down vote.. Looking forward to hear from you Thanks

Comment: Search the site for downgrading from Win8 to 7. There have been a couple of threads already, so this would probably end up being closed as a dupe. Short answer - no, it's not possible and you'd need to format and reinstall. Edit: And... now you possibly cannot delete because someone posted an answer.

Comment: @ZainShah120 - You cannot revert back to Windows 7 unless you made a backup of your hdd before you did so.

Comment: I am voting to close because a simple search would have lead you [here](http://superuser.com/questions/493643/how-to-backup-windows-7-and-revert-upgrade-to-windows-8), or [here](http://superuser.com/questions/474434/can-i-downgrade-from-windows-8-to-windows-7), or even [here](http://superuser.com/questions/494644/downgrading-from-windows-8-to-windows-7). As for the sarcasm, knock yourself out with more cracks if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible. You'll need to format your hard drive and reinstall Windows 7.