# Necessary Step before updating to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-7-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup Windows 7 and revert upgrade to Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/493643/how-to-backup-windows-7-and-revert-upgrade-to-windows-8)

Currently I am having Windows 7 Home Premium Edition in my laptop, I want to update my operating system to new latest Windows 8. What necessary step i need to take like taking backup of my operating system or create restore point ?

Moreoever if i want to switch back to my old operating system, does it allowed or not ?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/493643/how-to-backup-windows-7-and-revert-upgrade-to-windows-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to run the [Windows 8 upgrade assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) software in W7 **Before** you upgrade

Upgrade Assistant will scan your PC and look for driver and software conflicts, it may ask you to remove certain drivers or software before you upgrade, which is necessary and should not be skipped.

Also check your PC manufacturers website for W8 drivers for your specific model, you may need them.

Comment: +1 , this one really helps a lot to look into updation, without updating system :), thanks

Answer (score 0):

> "What necessary step i need to take like taking backup of my operating system or create restore point ?"

If you are referring to backing up personal files such as documents, pictures, or videos - fear not. Windows 8 will present an option to leave those files intact during the upgrade.

> "Moreoever if i want to switch back to my old operating system, does it allowed or not ?"

Unfortunately, no. According to [the Windows 8 FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/faq#section_7), you will need to use the original Windows 7 installation media to revert to Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to take the backup is to create an ISO with Norton Ghost.Depending upon the data the size of the image will be larger.you can store the data in External or internal HDD and then upload it to yor PC later on when required.The PC will go back to it previous postion.Download Norton Ghost and here is link to get started with it.http://youtu.be/LHwFx0EfO04 .Remember study and get knowledge of Norton Ghost and then  only implement it...

Thanks