# Upgrading windows 8 on Envy 13

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, upgrade, windows-8-upgrade

Maybe I'm a little noob... I want to upgrade to windows 8 my HP envy 13 but I've seen that HP doesn't provide any drivers for this pc. So I want to know if it is possible, or what should I do, or steps to follow in order to install windows 8 on my laptop. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the model number? You can download and run the Windows 8 [Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-assistant-advisor).

Comment: The link above gives you a more general overview on how to upgrade to Windows 8, and the things you should consider like system requirements. To get the Upgrade Advisor software, [click here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8). It will tell you what devices and programs and are compatible with Windows 8.

Comment: my laptop is envy 13-1050es, and I used upgrade advisor and it helped, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From site [HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03451712&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4062&product=4332662&softwareitem=ob-75801-1&sw_lang=):

> If you purchased your computer prior to October 1st , 2011, HP **has not
>   tested** or developed drivers for your model computer. Therefore an
>   upgrade of your computer might be difficult or impossible.

If you choose to upgrade your system, there is likely however is easily reversible.

> To restore the original operating system after upgrading, you must
>   create HP recovery media before you upgrade. To learn how to create
>   recovery media, see [**Creating Recovery Discs or Saving a Recovery
>   Image to a USB Flash Drive (Windows 7)**](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/doclink?lc=en&cc=us&product=4332662&tmp_docname=c01867124) .

Related: https://superuser.com/a/493675/219655