# Windows 8 upgrade - Can it dual-boot with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to the Windows 7 key when upgrading to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/486959/what-happens-to-the-windows-7-key-when-upgrading-to-windows-8)

I'm asking if the $39.99 offer here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy supports it. NOT if different versions of Windows in general can dual-boot.

My Windows 7 is OEM. I do not have any Windows 8 yet.