# Recovering the Windows 7 Product key, from a system upgraded to windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, product-key

I have a system that was running Windows 7 and then, back when Windows 8 was cheap, was upgraded to 8 (now 8.1 + Media Centre via separate updates & additions). Now I come to reformat / reinstall I need the original W7 key as I only have the upgrade licence for W8.

I understand that I can't use the W7 key *and* the W8 key due to the EULA ([What happens to the Windows 7 key when upgrading to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/486959/what-happens-to-the-windows-7-key-when-upgrading-to-windows-8)) and I appreciate that I can use a [registry hack](http://lifehacker.com/5984278/how-to-do-a-clean-install-of-windows-8-with-an-upgrade-disc) to bypass the need to actually install W7 first before W8. But, is it possible, in a "just in case" vain, to recover it somehow? I've got the W7 DVD somewhere, just nowhere I've looked so far.

*In a related but unrelated question: I've tried a couple of the key finder apps and they report the "Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center" product key only, but this is different to the W8 key I got when I bought it (I have that in an email); is that a normal thing and which would I use for the reinstall: original or updated?*

Edit: This is an OEM version of Windows 7 Pro but self-installed so the key is on the sticker on the DVD box. I was not foresightful enough to stick the sticker to the case however and the box eludes me.

Comment: Did the Windows 7 license come with the laptop?

Comment: There isn't anything to recover.  The only license you could recover would be the Windows 8.1 Professional w/ Media Center license.  Windows 8.1 Professional w/ Media Center is key is suppose to be seperate from the Windows 8.1 Professional Upgrade Key, that is normal, nothing strange about that.

Comment: If the license came with the computer, its often that the sticker with license code is placed somewhere on the case/laptop. Usually at the back or side. If you bought it seperately, you'll have to find the DVD box itself.

Comment: It's an OEM version of Windows 7 Pro on a Desktop, but self-built bought -from-a-shop OEM, rather than pre-installed. I'm pretty sure I left the sticker on the DVD case as I was afraid I'd lose it when/if I changed the case. It could only be more painfully ironic if I had spent years telling people to do exactly this to avoid losing it... wait...

Comment: Find the box or buy another license.