# Can I dual-boot my old Windows 7 with my free Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, license

I've upgraded my Windows 7 computer to Windows 10 using the free upgrade offer. Am I allowed to install Windows 7 again, alongside my new Windows 10 installation, or does the upgrade deal require me to choose which one I want to use, going forward?

Currently I still have the option to "Go back to Windows 7". Would I be right in thinking this "unlicenses" me for Windows 10?

Comment: Also: [Win7 to Win10, OS license usable for Windows 7 at later date?](http://superuser.com/questions/948356/win7-to-win10-os-license-usable-for-windows-7-at-later-date)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  The  answer might be the same but i'm not sure the linked duplicate applies.  Or are duplicates judged by the answer alone?

Comment: That's pretty much the catch all for "can I se my old licence after upgrading" question.  I also noted the other link as it was more specific to Win10, and more similar to your specific version of the question.  Feel free to request your question be reopened if you feel it's worthy as a stand alone question.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I read the answer there, and it refers specifically to some EULA text that does not appear in the Windows 10 EULA.